# magento 2.4 page cached after customer login

Tags: magento2.4, cache, customer-login

I have a simple text message that should change after customer logs in. So:

- when the customer lands on the page, he sees the text "please login"
- the customer clicks on "Please login", he gets redirected to the login page and, if he logs in correctly, he lands on the customer account dashboard page
- he then navigates back to the initial page

What I expect to see is my text message to be changed to "welcome"

What I see is, instead, still "please login" and I have to refresh the page to see the text changed in "welcome". If, after login, I land on a different page instead of a previous one, it works as expected and I see the "welcome" text with no need of refreshing.

So it's obviously a cache issue, although I cannot understand which cache I should clean

I have magento cache enabled, including the FPC but cleaning those doesn't change anything. Only by refreshing the page via browser I can see the changes.

Any idea on how to automatically trigger the change without the need for the customer to refresh the page?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default Magento, it runs without cache. this thing should be rendered using Private content. Maybe there is no issue with the cache. it seems like your local storage is not updating. please check your Magento log, Is there any issue?

for private content please check below links:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

https://aureatelabs.com/blog/how-to-use-private-content-or-sections-in-magento-2/

Comment: you are right, it is about private content. Product page has a knockout template to check wether the customer is logged in or not